# Select sql code in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Following query returning six values

```
SELECT tbl_start FROM timetable inner join route ON tbl_rte_id = id WHERE rte_origin = "UL" and rte_destination = "HW" ORDER BY(tbl_start) DESC;
```

And my laravel code is returning only one value

```
 $tables =   Timetable::join('route', 'tbl_rte_id', '=', 'id')
                            ->where('rte_origin', $origin, 'AND')
                            ->where('rte_destination', $destination)
                            ->orderBy('tbl_start', 'desc')
                            ->get();

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $result[$table->id] = $table->tbl_start;           
        }
```

This laravel code is not similar or similar. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
->where('rte_origin', $origin, 'AND')

// to:
->where('rte_origin', $origin)
```

It will know by default that it's `AND` operator

And if you want to provide this operator, then do this:

```
->where('rte_origin', '=', $origin, 'AND')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$tables = Timetable::join('route', 'tbl_rte_id', '=', 'timetable.id')
          ->where('rte_origin', $origin)
          ->where('rte_destination', $destination)
          ->orderBy('tbl_start', 'desc')
          ->get()->lists('tbl_start', 'id');
```

The `$tables` will contain an `array` of `id => tbl_start` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener in your routes.php

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql){
    var_dump($sql);
});
```

Then execute both queries and check if you have the same result